# I can't use the logical operator > in Flask

Tags: python-3.x, flask

In a template, I have the next loop, which is executed satisfactorily:

```
{% for cta_mega in ctas_mega_result %}
{% if cta_mega.cloud_delay == 0 %}
```

If I replace the last line with:

```
{% if cta_mega.cloud_delay > 0 %}
```

I get the following error:

**jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'dict object' has no attribute 'cloud_delay'**

Can anyone tell me that it is wrong? Doesn't Jinja2 support the ‘>’ operator?

Comment: Your issue does not result from the operator. This works as expected. As the error message states, `cloud_delay` is not included in the dict `cta_mega`.

Answer (score 1):

Jinja2 does support '>' operator
if your "ctas_mega_result" variable is of dictionary datatype and your naming the key as cta_mega then the for loop should have ".items" to get the key
{% for cta_mega in ctas_mega_result.items() %}

if cloud_delay is a key of the dictionary cta_mega then use cta_mega["cloud_delay"] to get the value.

check out this link for the syntax:
https://documentation.bloomreach.com/engagement/docs/jinja-syntax

Comment: '''ctas_mega_result''' is not a dictionary; it is a list. It is a list of dictionaries. Each of these dictionaries is identical and contains key-value pairs. One of these pairs has 'cloud_delay' as the key, and an integer as the value.
The interesting part is that the code works perfectly with the '==' logical operator, but it throws an error if it is changed to '>'.

Comment: Then did u check if the datatypes are the same on both sides since that could be a reason for greater than operator to fail

Comment: No problem related to the datatype. Just change the operator (with the same data set), so that the problem occurs.